# Web Speech

Tags: javascript, html5

Здравствуйте! У меня возникла следующая проблема. Я делаю сайт с голосовой навигацией. Тоесть если человек говорит, допустим, мой профиль, то его редеректит на страницу его профиля, и т.д. Я реализовал эту функцию и всё нормально работает, но только после загрузки страницы говорить можно в течении 5 секунд. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Ответить на этот вопрос сложно, если не знать как именно вы это реализовали. Звучит примерно как "я сделал часы, но они ходят только днём".

Comment: @makskovalko, может что-то ломается после полной загрузки страницы? Или буфер какой-нибудь переполняется? Посмотрите логи, потребление памяти...

Comment: Вот мой код 
var voice = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
voice.continuous = false;
voice.interimResults = true;
$(document).ready(function(){
voice.start();
});
voice.onresult = function(event) {
var messages = '';
for (var i=0; i<event.results.length; i++){
messages += event.results[i][0].transcript;}
switch (messages){case 'мои друзья':
window.location.href="friends.php";
break;
case 'все пользователи':
window.location.href="all_users.php";
break;
case 'мои фотографии':
window.location.href="index.php?p=photo&id=1";
break;
}}

Comment: @makskovalko слабо в вопрос добавить и отформатировать ?

Answer (score 1):

```
voice.continuous = true;
```

Спасибо, не знал о таком замечательном API!